# Value of Variable not properly passed as a Parameter to Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am declaring a variable "account" (assigned the value of accounts[0]), which I am trying to use as a parameter ("this.account") for calling the "this.login" method. The value of the variable is not properly passed. However, if I use the "accounts" variable instead to pass as a parameter, it works.

```
 data () {
   return {
    account: null
   }
 }

 this.web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
    this.account = accounts[0]
    if ((!sessionStorage) || (session === '')) {
      this.login(this.account)
    }
 })
```

I do not quite understand why I cannot successfully use the "this.account" variable as a parameter for calling the method this.login.

Comment: what is the value of `accounts`? Also, what does the `login` function look like?

Comment: Try debugging the assignment operation **this.account = accounts[0]** till calling of the login(). See if till there the value is proper.

Comment: can you add a `wrapping/parent` function to your question where `this.web3.eth.getAccounts` is called

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and time. I actually had a mistake in my code.